# md raid10: how to make sure that replicated data is stored in right place?

Tags: mdadm, raid10, diskmanagement, md

When creating classic mirrored raids, it's usual to locate copies of data on disks of different kinds. In this case you would use a mix of disks of different series and manufacturers. That reduces the risk of loosing data if a whole series is faulty.

Lets assume i want to build a md-based raid 10 with four disks built by two manufacturers. How can i ensure that data gets replicated on different typed disks?

I know there is the possiblity to specify the layout `near`, `far` and `offset` ([description](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man4/md.4.html)). These Layouts are pointing into the right direction, but i'm not sure how md "sorts" the disks. That could lead to copies on same typed disks.

Comment: Please explain **why** the order it does not matter. If a whole series has a failure (for example by failed design) and the data gets replicated on a disk of same series, the data may be lost in a short amount of time (e.g. hours).

Comment: If you have a three-disk failure in this scenario, then you're _incredibly_ unlucky. Of course, the potential for being so unfortunate is one reason why you also need backups.

Comment: When using raid 10 with for disks, only tolerance for one disk-failure is "guaranteed". If the _wrong_ two disks fail, the data is lost. So if replication happens on disks of same manufacturer/series disks it's more likely that data gets lost.

I'm aware that raid is not a backup. It just makes storage with higher availability possible.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think you are assuming RAID-1 with four replicas, but that is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, really want to guarantee that you pair drives from manufacturer 1 and manufacturer 2, you should probably set up the mdadm raid 10 manually.

Use `lshw -class disk` as a superuser, to verify the logical names of each of the disks, and the vendor names.

Then create the underlying RAID 1 devices for your raid 10:

`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`

`mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1`

Then assemble the RAID 1 devices into a RAID 0 device.

`mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/md1`

Which should give you a RAID 10 where you know which devices are paired with which.

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: So in short: it's not possible to set the replication layout completely manually via md's raid 10. The solution is a raid 1+0.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you probably found a way around this by now but the following should do the trick:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda missing /dev/sdc missing
```

Where sda and sdc are of different manufacturers. 
Then add the missing disks with:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdd
```

When running the mdadm --create command, order seemed to matter for sure, so I'd assume that, as long as the 1st and 3rd disk (in a 4 drive array) are of different manufacturers, you'd get the same effect, but you should test that one for yourself.